# Insert Latest Articles in Homepage

Tags: homepage, blog

How can I insert the latest articles (blog) on top of the homepage?

I intend with the release of the latest items with image and brief summary of the article.

I made an example (in the attached image) of I intend to do.

[image]

I want to have some articles (eg. inside similar box design below).

ps: I'm a beginner, please be patient and simple.

Thanks!!

Comment: "I'm a beginner" or "Thing is not working" is not a valid excuse for learning, but "I'm learning, I'm trying heart & soul, but thing is not working as expected" can be. Just try to get some idea with the following resources: Download [TwentyFourteen](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyfourteen), and see the code. See [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and learn how to fetch custom data from the `db`. And show us what you've done already... nobody will touch your blank sheet of paper, you have to paint it first, somebody can retouch only to fine-tune.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the home page template and add the following code :

```
<h2>Recent Posts</h2>
<ul>
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '1' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
    }
?>
</ul>
```

I have used `<UL>` and `<li>` to list post.... You can use your own html & css to style.

You can use different wordpress functions, One I have used is `get_permalink()` to get the post URL, similarly you can use `get_the_post_thumbnail()` to get the featured image of the post.